# Centering a slideshow with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to develop a website to better my web development understanding and have run into an issue implementing a website. I am struggling figuring out how to neatly center my slideshow I have implemented for the home screen so i can develop my header, footer and nav bar around it. Any help on this end would be greatly appreciated. the HTML code used looks like this.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0px;
}

slider {
  display: block;
  width: 1280px;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

slider>* {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #1f1f1f;
  animation: slide 12s infinite;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

slide:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0%;
  animation-delay: -1s;
  background-image: url(1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

slide:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
  background-image: url(2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

slide:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 5s;
  background-image: url(3.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

slide:nth-child(4) {
  left: 0%;
  animation-delay: 8s;
  background-image: url(4.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

slide p {
  font-family: Comfortaa;
  font-size: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 340px;
  color: #fff;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    left: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  5% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  25% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  30% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  30.0001% {
    left: -100%;
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
    width: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<slider>
  <slide>
    <p>Slide 1</p>
  </slide>
  <slide>
    <p>Slide 2</p>
  </slide>
  <slide>
    <p>Slide 3</p>
  </slide>
  <slide>
    <p>Slide 4</p>
  </slide>
</slider>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to center the `slider` in the body. If so, you need to change `absolute` by `relative` of `position` of `slider`.

```
slider {
    display: block;
    width: 1280px;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Comment: Appreciated i didn't really understand the difference on positioning terms reading about them why exactly does that make it center? and is there a way to make it middle center?

Comment: There are two types of centers: vertically and horizontally. Do you mean vertically center?

Comment: yes i want it running through the middle of the website like a body with room for a header and footer bar above and under

Answer (score 0):

You can center-align the slider by many ways. Like using the `center` tag although it is not recommended.

> **Obsolete**
>   
>   This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

---

You can change your css code to this:

```
slider {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    // margin: 0 auto;
}
```

---

Or you can enclose `slider` in a `div` and add `text-align: center` to the div (aka wrapper or container) and add `display: inline-block` to `slider`

---

If you want to keep your `position: absolute`, then you can write your css like this.

```
slider {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: 640px; //half of the width
    // you can also use: 
    // transform: translate(-50%, 0px);
    // instead of margin-left
}
```

Also see these two for more ways and explanation:

> https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp
>   https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-center-things-with-style-in-css-dc87b7542689/

Comment: for some reason implementing these makes the slider disappear when i test it.